# Generic DBContext for Where Query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

so I am trying to make a generic function for a where query, not using repository
so it is possible to do something like this?

```
   public IEnumerable<T> Something<T>(int authorId) where T : class
    {
        return Vmsb.Set<T>().Where(c => c.AuthorId== authorId);

    }
```

now I can't because it dont know what c.AuthorId is

Comment: Why don't you try and see if it's possible?

Comment: i try and I can't so Iam asking, it is possible to do it in some other way, in generic dont know how te know the property in the where clause

Comment: Well, think of it this way. BookContext has a table for type `Book`, and PeopleContext has a table for type `Person`. With such a function you could ask BookContext to give you a `Person` object, which would result in an exception. What are you trying to achieve with this abstraction?

Comment: make a generic where for my dropdowlist that use in all my page
and "authorId" would be my foreing key in almost all my tables

Comment: But why does the DB need to be generic? Also, since `T : class`, why would it have a property called `AuthorId`? In your sample you do `Set<T>().Where(c => c.AuthorId...)`. But how would `T` know of this property? Why don't you just use a Repository?

Comment: But how would T know of this property?.
 that is what i want to know if is posible, my system is well advanced and for know can use repository

Comment: @Diego_DX, are you using Code First or Database (Model) First approach?

Answer (score 5):

Create an interface `IHaveAuthor` and specify it on partial classes with this property:

```
public interface IHaveAuthor
{
    int AuthorId { get; set; }
}

//Note that the interface is already implemented in auto-generated part.
//Or if it's Code First, just specify it directly on your classes.
public partial class Book : IHaveAuthor
{
}

public partial class Article : IHaveAuthor
{
}
```

Then point the interface under the generic type [`where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) constraint:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAuthorPublicationsOf<T>(int authorId) 
    where T : class, IHaveAuthor
{
    return Vmsb.Set<T>().Where(c => c.AuthorId == authorId);
}
```

And the usage:

```
var authorBooks = query.GetAuthorPublicationsOf<Book>(authorId);
var authorArticles = query.GetAuthorPublicationsOf<Article>(authorId);
```

Comment: I've used this strategy with EF Code First in my own code - this works.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to [Olexander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15845090/176877), since EF recommends you use the Unit of Work pattern, I usually don't assume a DbContext in my methods - I pass in the most generic object possible instead. Also just as a matter of style, I like to return the interface.

**EDIT** Updated to include Olexander's important fix to use IQueryable instead of IEnumerable.

So my method signature would look like:

```
public IQueryable<IHaveAuthor> Something(int authorId, IQueryable<IHaveAuthor> items)
{
    return items.Where(c => c.AuthorId == authorId);
}
```

So calling this would be a bit different than your current calls to it - presumably something like:

```
var db = new MyDbContext();
var items = db.Books;
var itemForAuthor1 = Something(1, items);
```

Otherwise your "Something" method isn't terribly flexible - it assumes a single existing DbContext on your current object which might not be a safe assumption (since it's only supposed to live as long as this small chunk of work, whatever it is), you can't chain it with other commands, etc.

Comment: Chris, thanks for quoting me;) I have updated my answer to be seemed more pretty. Could you fix the link as it references to 404 now? Thanks!

Comment: And I would consider passing `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. In your code sample it will enumerate all the entities in web server memory instead of SQL query execution. So if you have million rows in db table, you will definitely face to significant performance problems.

Comment: @Olexander Fixed the link. The IEnumerable assertion you make however is incorrect; the code I have above won't cause items to be enumerated in memory - the query will wait to fire off until you take a later action like calling .ToArray(). Try it.

Comment: Chris, let's bet on 100 reputation?;) Just for fun).
I don't mean the delayed execution. I mean in your code sample, after you call `itemForAuthor1.ToArray()`, `ToList()`, `Count()`, `foreach` or whatever, SQL Server will process query `"select ... from Book"` instead of `"select ... from Book where AuthorId=1"` and the authors will be filtered in memory on object level by enumerating all the books. So, you won't get any benefit of indexes and if there are 100 books, you may not even notice the performance impact, but if there are 1 million books, ooops;) And that can be easily proved..

Comment: Right, and I'm not calling ToArray(), ToList(), Count(), or foreach in my example code, meaning it won't be enumerated early. So, whether I'm passing IEnumerable or IQueryable is irrelevant - either way it still waits to run actual SQL. In my example code, that's sometime after my call to "Something" (some call later that enumerates the data). So your IQueryable vs IEnumerable assertion is incorrect, and my code will not in fact enumerate all the entities in web server memory instead of SQL query execution.

Comment: I've separated this out into its own question and added demo code to prove this IEnumerable approach doesn't fire off unnecessary SQL there: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15893180/176877 Back on-topic, what's nice about this approach is you can decorate your query with any number of functions and logic before actually firing it off, which can make queries much more composable.

Comment: I have added some considerations regarding IQueryable<T> and IEnumerable<T> to my blog: http://ivanitskyi.blogspot.com/2013/04/entity-framework-iqueryable-vs-ienumerable.html

Answer (score 0):

Diego hope my code helps u.

```
   protected List<T> ListAll<T>() where T : class
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ()) 
        {
            return db.Set(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().AsNoTracking<T>().ToList();
        }

    }


    protected T ListAllById<T>(int id) where T : class
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ()) 
        {
            return db.Set(typeof(T)).Cast<T>().Find(id);
        }
    }

    protected void InsertObj(Object obj)
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext()) 
        {
            db.Set(obj.GetType()).Add(obj);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    protected void UpdateObj(Object obj)
    {    
        try
        {
            using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
            {
                db.Set(obj.GetType()).Attach(obj);
                db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(" " + ex.Message);
        }            
    }

    protected void DeleteObj(Object obj)
    {
        using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext ())
        {
            db.Set(obj.GetType()).Attach(obj);
            db.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please add a brief description of what the code does instead of just posting the code.