# When exactly does Entity Framework Fire a SQL Command?

Tags: sql, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

Suppose I have code like:

```
public void TestWhenSqlFires()
{
    var db = new Db(); // EF DbContext
    var items = db.SimpleObjects; // SimpleObject implements interface IId
    var byId = WhereId(items, 1);
    var array = byId.ToArray();
}

protected IEnumerable<IId> WhereId(IEnumerable<IId> items, int id)
{
    return items.Where(i => i.Id == id);
}
```

At what line in TestWhenSqlFires() will SQL actually be run against the database?

(This is a question that spun off from comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15845220/176877))

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out and test for yourself:

Open SQL Server Management Studio, open a new query, select the database EF will be running against and run this query:

```
SELECT top 10 deqs.last_execution_time AS [Time], dest.TEXT AS [Query]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
ORDER BY deqs.last_execution_time DESC
```

This tells you the past 10 queries that have run against the database.

Set a breakpoint on the first line of TestWhenSqlFires(), run your code, then run the above query after stepping over each line. You'll find:

```
// C# Line 1
var db = new Db();

--SQL Line 1
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA SchemaName, TABLE_NAME Name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

// C# Line 2
var items = db.SimpleObjects;

--SQL Line 2
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [sys].[databases] WHERE [name]=@1

SELECT [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1] FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(1) AS [A1] FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
) AS [GroupBy1]

(@1 nvarchar(4000))SELECT TOP (1) [Project1].[C1] AS [C1],
    [Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId],
    [Project1].[Model] AS [Model]  FROM (
        SELECT [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId],
            [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model], 1 AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
     )  AS [Project1]  ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC

// C# Line 3
var byId = WhereId(items, 1);

--SQL Line 3

// C# Line 4
var array = byId.ToArray();

--SQL Line 4
SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], [Extent1].[Stuff] AS [Stuff]
    FROM [dbo].[SimpleObject] AS [Extent1]
```

The final SQL query is EF actually fetching the data. The prior queries are just it warming up - verifying the database exists, that it's using EF5 Migration History, and that it matches the current Migration History hash.

So the answer is - the 4th line, after `.ToArray()` is called (or any call that enumerates the collection, like .ToList(), foreach, etc). Notably passing it to a method that accepts IEnumerable, even if there's a specific Generic involved, does not enumerate the collection, and so does not fire off SQL any earlier than necessary.

Comment: Chris, check the last query: `SELECT Id, Stuff FROM SimpleObject`. And what you might have expected: `SELECT Id, Stuff FROM SimpleObject WHERE Id=1`. It means your `Where` extension method is applied against objects collection that contains all SimpleObjects (which are returned by actual query). So it does enumerate the collection as there is no other way to complete `Where` method. It wouldn't enumerate if you passed IQueryable instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: @Olexander I see now, I apologize - I misunderstood. I see now that if I change it to IQueryable it does in fact change the SQL - you're right it's enumerating it all in memory - terrible!

Comment: No problem, we have finally reached an agreement;)